# Why are the values of a variable lost after a function call in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

Why is the passed variable "list" after performing the function "test" empty i.e. accessing the elements of list or freeing the pointer list result in a memory leak?

What am I missing?

```
int test(int** container)
{
    int numOfItems = 2;
    int* p1;
    int* p2;
    int j=0;

    container = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*) * numOfItems);
    for(j=0;j<numOfItems;j++)
         container[j] = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));

    *(container[0]) = 12;
    *(container[1]) = 13;
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{ 
    int* list;
    test(&list);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
container = (int**) malloc (sizeof(int*) * numOfItems);
```

should be

```
*container = malloc (sizeof(int*) * numOfItems);
```

`container` is only a local variable, a copy of the `int* list`.

Also, you generally [should not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the return of `malloc`.